# General Topology, continous related to disconnection among a set

Tags: general-topology

Prove: Show that if $f$ is continuous and if $O_{1}$ and $O_{2}$ disconnect $f(A)$, then $f^{-1}(O_{1})$ and $f^{-1}(O_{2})$ disconnect $A$.

Definitions:
A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $p\in \mathbb{R}$ if for every open set $V_{f(p)}$ containing $f(p)$ there exists an open set $U_{p}$ covering $p$ such that $f[U_{p}]\subset V_{f(p)}$

I just have a question regarding what my professor means by disconnect? He is a kind old irishman and he sometimes forgets to explain in class what he wants. Anywyas if anyone could help assist me with what I need to do, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You will probably want to use a different definition of continuous.

Comment: It is the only definition he gave us

Comment: The non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ disconnect the space $X$ if $U\cup V=X$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$

Comment: @MorganWeiss your class probably covered the statement that $f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for every open $U$.

Comment: Or perhaps you can use the statement "$A$ is disconnected iff there is an onto continuous map $f:A\to\{0,1\}$".

Comment: see the edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition 1**: If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$ satisfies that for every open set $V \in Y$, $f^{-1}(V)\in X$ is open, then $f$ is continuous.
**Definition 2**: The non-empty open sets $U$ and $V$ disconnect the space $X$ if $U\cup V=X$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

By definition 1, we know that $f^{-1}(O_1)$ and $f^{-1}(O_2)$ are open. They are non-empty because $O_1$ and $O_2$ are non-empty. Finally, $f^{-1}(O_1)\cup f^{-1}(O_2)=f^{-1}(O_1\cup O_2)=f^{-1}(f(A))=A$.